# Asp.net Core RequestSizeLimit still executes action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I am using ASP.net Core 2.0 with MVC. I have a controller action that I want to limit the request size to 1MB. I added the `RequestSizeLimit` attribute like so:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[RequestSizeLimit(1_000_000)]
public async Task<List<ResourceUploadResult>> Upload([FromBody]List<Resource> updatedList){
    //....
}
```

When the upload is < 1MB, it works as expected. When it is > 1MB I expected the server to return a status of 413, but instead, the `updatedList` parameter is null and the action executes normally, running into a `NullReferenceException` when it tries to iterate the list.

Is there a way to tell Kestrel to return 413 when the size limit is reached?

Comment: I test your code with `.NET Core 2.0.0`, but it runs flawlessly. Is there a project that can reproduce this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best, but it will work in the mean time.

```
if(updatedList == null)
      return StatusCode(413, "Payload to big") ;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can limit the size globally by

```
.UseKestrel(kestrolOptions =>
{
    kestrolOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 1_000_000;
..
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away when I upgraded to 2.1. I can't say for sure that 2.0 has a bug, but after updating all the NuGet packages to 2.1 it behaved as expected.

It's unfortunate that I don't have more information about the cause since others seeking a solution to this problem may not be able to just upgrade their version like I did.